# Windows powershell simplify file names

Tags: powershell

I've got many files with names like the following format:

`File name Revision_Series.random_obs1.random_obs2-random_obs3.txt`

The idea would be to strip everything from Revision_Series until the file extension.

Revision_Series will always have the format Rxx where xx is 2 digits.

> Costea Voda 4A R03.Showed-Unliked.Has4Changes.zip
>
> Costea Voda 4A R11.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip

which should become

> Costea Voda 4A R03.zip
>
> Costea Voda 4A R11.zip

Comment: Could you paste in a screen shot of some of the file names?  I am not sure what the files actually look like, or edit in the results of `Get-childItem | select -first 10` into your post.

Comment: `-a----       10/31/2019   2:42 PM      309384285 Costea Voda 4A R03.Showed-Unliked.Has4Changes.zip
-a----       10/31/2019   2:41 PM      324001213 Costea Voda 4A R11.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip`

Plan would be to be left with Costea Voda 4A R11.zip

Comment: PLEASE add two or three realistic, FULL file names to your Original Post, and then add the desired result for each of those sample files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get name collisions of course by doing this:

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\'    #'# put the path of the folder containing the files here
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -File | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -split '\.')[0], $_.Extension
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName -WhatIf
}
```

If you are satisfied with the info shown in the console, remove the `-WhatIf` switch to actually have the code renaming the files.

Answer (score 0):

I made a directory with some fake files like this:

```
Directory: C:\temp\example


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                        
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 1 R1.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 1 R2.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 1 R3.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 2 R1.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 2 R2.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 2 R3.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 3 R1.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 3 R2.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 3 R3.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 4 R1.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 4 R2.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip                                                                  
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 4 R3.Showed-Liked.Is.Final.zip
```

This short script will remove the `.Showed-Liked` etc, everything after `R#` and up to the extension.

```
$files = dir C:\temp\example 
foreach($file in $files){
    $nameComponents = $file.Name.Split(".")
    Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $($nameComponents[0] + $file.Extension) -PassThru
}
```

After

```
Directory: C:\temp\example


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                        
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 1 R1.zip                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 1 R2.zip                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 1 R3.zip                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 2 R1.zip                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 2 R2.zip                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 2 R3.zip                                                                                        
-a----       10/31/2019   9:50 AM              0 Costea Voda 3 R1.zip
```